# Extract Classification Function In Supervised Learning

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, supervised-learning

Possibly I am asking a trivial question but the answer is so crucial to me.
I'm really new to machine learning.I have read about Supervised learning and I know basics of these kind of algorithms.The question is when I'm using an algorithm such as j48 on a dataset how can I find the specified Function to use later to classify unlabeled data.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Function" you are refering to is a classifier itself. It is being learned during the training procedure. Consequently, in order to use your model to classify new data you have to dump it to disk/database. How? It depends completely on the language/implementation used. For python you would simply pickle an object. In Java you can serialize your trained object or use Weka to learn j48 decision tree and save it for later use:
https://weka.wikispaces.com/Saving+and+loading+models

Comment: Really appreciate that!